# How do I specify record TTL in OpenSearch?

Tags: opensearch, amazon-opensearch

How do I define default record ttl for an index?

I read through OpenSearch's [create index docs](https://opensearch.org/docs/2.6/api-reference/index-apis/create-index/), but can't find how to define default ttl for an index.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:** `The _ttl mappings have been removed. As a replacement for _ttl mappings, we recommend using ILM to create time-based indices.` https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/8.7/mapping-ttl-field.html

### TTL = index retention period in Elasticsearch/Opensearch.

- In elasticsearch, it's called [ILM policy](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/index-lifecycle-management.html).
- In opensearch, it's called [ISM policy](https://opensearch.org/docs/latest/im-plugin/ism/index/).

UPDATE:
You can use delete by query with time range filter.

```
POST my-index-000001/_delete_by_query?routing=1
{
  "query": {
    "range" : {
        "field_name" : {
           "lte" : "now-10d"
        }
    }
  }
}
```

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-delete-by-query.html

Comment: Thanks for answering this! What I am looking for is record ttl, not index ttl. I don't want to delete the index, but delete a record after a certain period of time.

Comment: You can use _delete_by_query API call.

Comment: _delete_by_query is manual delete. I remember ElasticSearch has a _ttl field, but I am not sure whether OpenSearch support it.

Comment: `The _ttl mappings have been removed. As a replacement for _ttl mappings, we recommend using ILM to create time-based indices.` https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/8.7/mapping-ttl-field.html